# How to use javascript to create auto refresh data only for Repeaters in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to do a mail system in inbox with function auto refresh in repeaters only for data.How to do it?

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsInbox">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <tr id="trInbox" class="normal" style='cursor:pointer; font-weight:<%# StyleBold(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("inbRead")) ) %>' onclick='selectedRow(this,<%# Eval("INBID") %>)'   onMouseOver="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#E2E1F4';" onMouseOut="if(this.className!='selected') this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"> 
            <td width="370px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# DisplaySubject(Eval("inbSubject").ToString(), Eval("inbMsg").ToString())%></div></td> 
            <td width="80px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# Eval("inbCreatedAt","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %></div></td> 
            <td width="94px" height="25px"><div align="left" class="style95">&nbsp;<%# Eval("inbCreatedAt","{0:hh:mm:ss tt}") %></div></td> 
          </tr>   
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET's timer control inside an `UpdatePanel` together with your repeater, every tick event that the timer invokes, you can rebind your repeater.

here is a sample ASPX markup of my suggestion:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="30000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
                // Your Repeater Template    
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and for your code behind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater1.Datasource = // Whatever your datasource is
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```